# Transferring the bean class to another package

Tags: java, spring

I had the `AuthorizationServiceImpl` class in the `web` module in the `security` package, which is bean https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/web/web/security/service/impl/AuthorizationServiceImpl.java. In my latest version of the project, I moved the `AuthorizationService` and `AuthorizationServiceImpl` class to the `core` module. You can see it on the screen https://zapodaj.net/866eab42f00f0.png.html. However, IntelliJ throws me an error during compilation

```
2018-04-04 02:10:15.578  WARN 1688 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.web.WebApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'authorizationService' for bean class [com.core.service.impl.AuthorizationServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.web.web.security.service.impl.AuthorizationServiceImpl] As if IntelliJ did not know that I moved the class to another package and throws me into conflict with the previous place, but the class is not there anymore.
```

How do you let IntelliJ know that the class has been moved?

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem on line 1:

`package com.web.web.security.service.impl;`

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild project? Looks like src files in web directory are not up to date.